# How to grab all the lines with readline function in python?

Tags: python

grabc is a tool for output the colour code and RGB value.
When I use it, the output looks like this.

```
$grabc

'#000051'

'0,0,81'
```

I used this program for grabbing the output

```
import os

p=os.popen('grabc')

s=p.readline()

p.close()

print "a="+s


>>> "a=#000051"
```

but I want

```
>>> "a=#000051

0,0,81"
```

as the output
what should I do to grab the second line.

I am using python. And I need to grab the whole output in a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use `lines = p.readlines()` instead. This will read not one, but all the lines from the output and return them as a list of strings. However, instead of `os.popen` you may want to use the corresponding functions of the newer [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module instead.

You can use `"".join(lines)` to join the list of strings to a single string. Since the lines still have their original line end character, you can just use `""` as delimiter. Alternatively, you could `strip` the line end characters and use your own delimiter: `"\n".join([l.strip() for l in lines])`.

Also, note that you do not *assign* the output to the variable `a` at all, but just print it that way. Further, depending on what you want to do with the color values, it might be better to leave them separate and assign them to different variables instead.

---

**Update:** On closer inspection, it seems that not all the output of `grabc` is captured this way, neither with `subprocess` or even when doing `grabc > some_file`. The hex-string is captured, but the color tuple is not. However, you can easily convert one value into the other, so this should not be a problem.

```
h = "#a7bd7a"
t = 167,189,122
"#%02x%02x%02x" % t                              # color tuple to hex string
[int(h[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(1, len(h), 2)] # hex string to color tuple
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment. `readlines` command is helpful but for some reason grabc does not take all the values in readlines.  After running the py file The answer come like this
`0,0,193
Value of readlines=
['#0000c1\n']` Answer is ['#0000c1\n'] but I hoped for the answer would be  `['0,0,193' '#0000c1\n']`

Comment: I see now what you mean. Strangely, not all the output of `grabc` seems to land in `p.readlines()`... same when using `subprocess` module. Well, you could still reproduce the numeric values from the hexadecimal...